# How to move folder from local drive to Sharepoint folder using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

My sample code:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential
Add-PnPStoredCredential -Name $URL -Username $Creds.UserName -Password $Creds.Password

Import-Module SharePointPnPPowershellOnline
$URL = "https://myweb.sharepoint.com/sites/abc"
connect-PnPOnline $URL

$SourceFolder = "C:\Users\myLocation"
$TargetFolder = "Shared Documents/Sample Images"

#Get-PnPList
Move-PnPFolder -Folder $SourceFolder -TargetFolder $TargetFolder
```

I got the following error message:

```
Move-PnPFolder : File Not Found.
At C:\Users\MyLocation\PowerShell\FileUpload.ps1:14 char:1
+ Move-PnPFolder -Folder $SourceFolder -TargetFolder $TargetFolder
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Move-PnPFolder], ServerException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.MoveFolder
```

I used the module SharePointPnPPowershellOnline for connect with Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only move a folder from one SharePoint location to another using Move-PnPFolder. It is not supported moving the folder from local. As stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/move-pnpfolder?view=sharepoint-ps

> Move a folder to another location in the current web.

Please refer to below articles to upload a folder to SharePoint using PowerShell.

- **[SharePoint Online: Upload a Folder using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/01/upload-folder-to-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html)**
- **[SharePoint Online: Migrate a Folder with Sub-Folders and Files to SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/sharepoint-online-migrate-folder-with-files-subfolders-using-powershell.html)**